# Recognize built-in scanner availability Flutter Web

Tags: flutter

I have a Honeywell EDA51-0 Android phone with a built-in laser scanner, I'm developing a flutter web (PWA) app and I want to assert via code something similar:

```
if (laser scanner is available)
   //Do something
else 
   //Do something else
```

I didn't find any plugin that can provide the condition, do someone know a way?

I found some plugins that of course support android platform, not really a check from the browser

Searched online for suitab le plugins, but seems the browser cannot access this hardware information